# Making use of Google Map in an Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to use Google Map in an Android app for the first time.
For that I found a couple of tutorials and documents on the net to get started.
I already have an API key that I got from Google.

Here is the kind of code I have:

```
package me.myapp

import ....

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }


     override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}
```

I can launch the app I made, but something is not what I expected:

- When installed and launched on my device the app appears with the name *MapsActivity* instead of the usual name I give (*MyApp*). I don't know if this is important, but I just wonder why that is.
- After it is launched, I see a grey display with the *Google* mark at the bottom left, but no other contents. I expected to see some map of Sidney appear.

I hope someone reading this will have some relevant feedback to provide.
Thanks in advance.

......... addition .........

Here is how the AndroidManifest.xml file  looks like, in case that may be useful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="me.myapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The app screenshot is:

[image]

Comment: Did you enable the location permission from settings for your app?

Comment: Check your log....

Comment: @Abdullah. No I did not and I think I did not see that mentioned in what I read. Where should I do that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57098852/how-to-ask-for-location-permission-in-android-studio

Comment: For instant check add the permissions in the manifest of your app and enable it from app settings. Mobile Settings -> apps-> your app-> permissions-> location ->enable it

Comment: @Abdullah. Thanks but are you sure  you are not making a confusion? I only need to have a map. I do not need to the know the device current location and the GPS.

Comment: @Gobu CSG. I read this in the logs:
-- 
In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
--

The problem is that when I go to the URL mentioned I see no "Google Maps Android API v2".

Comment: Add this to you manifest:
[Solution provided in similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29960428/16732181)

Comment: @Michel Key and Json file. Cross check both. Check your studio log as well.

Comment: @azaLiza. I have tried your link. It does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please Provide your Google Map Api Key**

1. Create google api key [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGTG1l7yin4)
2. Enter the Key you got in the value field

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="pasteApiKey" />
```

Comment: My API is already set up from start.

Comment: Yes. I needed to go to
https://console.cloud.google.com
and then enable "Maps SDK for Android" in the library section.
Thanks a lot for this help!
I found this detail looking at your vidéo.

Answer (score 0):

To change the name of your application you need to open the Manifest file and change the string label inside the application and activity tag :

```xml
<application
   android:label="MyApp"
   <activity
      android:label="MyApp"
   </activity>
</application>
```

To access location you need to add these permissions in the Manifest file as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And make sure to request the use of location when launching your app
This decomuntation tells how to do it :
[Request location in android apps](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions)

Comment: In the the Manifest file, when I look the name is already "MyApp" so there is nothing I can change.
For the rest I do not need to access location, I only want a map.

Comment: Have you checked inside of the activity tag if the string of label is MyApp as well ?
Can you post a screenshot of the result when you launch your mapp please ?

Comment: I have updated my post to provide more information. Please take a look.

Comment: for the name change this line  (android:label="@string/title_activity_maps") into  (android:label="@string/app_name")

Comment: Yes for the name that worked. But am I supposed to do that? Beside I added a screenshot to the post.